# Linux socket value

Tags: c, sockets

I have a client-server program, on the server side:

```
sockListen = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

`socketListen` always seems to equal 3. Why? how about 0, 1 or 2? What is the value range of sockets in Linux?

Comment: I could be completely wrong but I think Linux hands out file handles by integer and 0 usually is STDIN, 1 is STDOUT, and 2 is STDERR. So the first handle you are given would then be 3. Would need clarification by someone who actually knows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

0, 1, and 2 are stdin, stdout, and stderr, respectively.  3 is the next available one.  If you created another, or opened a file, etc., it'd get 4.  And so and and so forth.

But you shouldn't rely on this at all.  Code your application to treat the integers as opaque objects.  Only compare them to values to see if they're negative (indicating an error).

Answer (score 6):

The return value is a file descriptor. File descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are already open. (stdin, stdout and stderr, respectively)